# When text box is length is 0 change HTML table td color?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to make a table change a td depending on what is in my text document. If the doc is empty I want it to have a white background with black text, but if there is content inside the document then set the background to grey with white text. It also echos what's in the document in the second td. It works if there is something in the document but if I change the document to "" it works but if I use my text box to set this value by clearing it with back spaces it doesn't work. The td is still grey with white text even know there isn't anything being display in it. Anyone got any ideas here?

**Text Box Setter**

```
<?php
$tb = $_POST['spo']."\r\n";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $myFile=fopen("DATA/Spo.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        fwrite($myFile, $tb);
        fclose($myFile);
        header("Location: SeniorManagersSiteTour.php");

    }
?>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Site / Project / Office</h1>
    <form action="SiteProjectOffice.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
        <input name="spo" type="text" size="size" maxlength="22" <?php $myFile=fopen("DATA/Spo.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!"); echo 'value="'.fgets($myFile).'"'; fclose($myFile); ?>>

        <div id="btnDiv">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**$Spo**

```
$myFile=fopen("DATA/Spo.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$Spo = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);
```

**Table**

```
<table border="0" width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                    <td width="26%" height="20px" <?php if (strlen($Spo) == 0){echo'bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color:black;"';}else{echo'bgcolor="999999" style="color:white;"';}?>><strong>Site / Project / Office</strong></td>
                    <td width="26%" height="20px" onclick="location.href='SiteProjectOffice.php'"<?php if (strlen($Spo) == 0){echo'bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color:black;"';}else{echo'bgcolor="999999" style="color:white;"';}?>><?php echo $Spo; ?></td>
                    <td width="21%" height="20px"><strong>Contract Number</strong></td>
                    <td width="27%" height="20px" onclick="location.href='ContractNumber.php'"><?php $myFile=fopen("DATA/Cont.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!"); echo fgets($myFile); fclose($myFile); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td height="20px" ><strong>Site Manager</strong><td colspan="4" onclick="location.href='SiteManager.php'"><?php $myFile=fopen("DATA/Site.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!"); echo fgets($myFile); fclose($myFile); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td height="20px"><strong>Job / Task Description</strong><td colspan="4" onclick="location.href='JobTaskDescription.php'"><?php $myFile=fopen("DATA/Job.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!"); echo fgets($myFile); fclose($myFile); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: See, the thing about PHP is that  it _only_ runs before code/data leaves the server for your browser. Once the data has left the server, PHP's job is done. If you want to react to user's input, you'll need to use javascript too. Have a look (in the browser) at the page's source code after you've loaded the page - notice that all of the php tags are now gone? They've been evaluated and a static output sent based on them.Now change something in the php so the onscreen appearance is different. Again, view-source of the page. Notice they're different? Javascript is for you. Consider w3schools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment above, consider the following HTML/JS snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('srcElem').addEventListener('input', onInputChanged, false);
}

function onInputChanged(evt)
{
    var srcElem = byId('srcElem');
    var curText = srcElem.value;

    // will range from 0 to 350, in steps of 10
    var curHue = (curText.length % 36) * 10;

    var tgt = byId('tgtElem');
    tgt.style.color = 'hsl(' + curHue + ',100%,50%)';
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id='tgtElem'>I can change colour...</h1>
    <hr>
    Type here to change the colour of the title (colour cycles every 36 characters)<br>
    <textarea id='srcElem'></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

And again, this time as a copy you can run right here on the page.
Simply hit "show snippet" and then hit the "Run Code Snipet" button that appears. :)

```js
    "use strict";
    function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
    
    window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
    
    function onDocLoaded()
    {
        // the change event only fires when we lose focus with a different value
        // than we had when gaining focus.
        // the input event on the other hand, responds to each keystroke, also
        // to cut/paste actions.
     byId('srcElem').addEventListener('input', onInputChanged, false);
    }
    
    function onInputChanged(evt)
    {
     var srcElem = byId('srcElem');
        // because the event handler has been attached to the element, the handler
        // can now be considered a part of the element.
        // This means that the 'this' keyword holds a reference to the object that
        // triggered the event. In this case, the event is only attached to one
        // element, so the element that generated the event is unambiguous and
        // must be the <textarea>
        //  We can use the same handler for many different elements though.
        // at that point (and this one too) it's far better and more powerful to
        // use the 'this' keyword.
        // i.e  var curText = this.value;
        // Try adding more textarea elements (each with a unique id) and attaching
        // the same event to each of them. By using the above line of code instead
        // of the below one, the text colour will depend on the length of text in
        // the most recently typed-in box.
    
     var curText = srcElem.value;
     
     // will range from 0 to 350, in steps of 10
     var curHue = (curText.length % 36) * 10;
     
     var tgt = byId('tgtElem');
     tgt.style.color = 'hsl(' + curHue + ',100%,50%)';
    }
```

```html
     <h1 id='tgtElem'>I can change colour...</h1>
     <hr>
     Type here to change the colour of the title (colour cycles every 36 characters)<br>
     <textarea id='srcElem'></textarea>
```